# Is there a way to use ZoomIt / Magnifier for Touch Devices?

Tags: windows-7, zoom, touch, magnifier

I have Windows 7 on my Tablet, and hitting the right buttons is a pain.

Anyhow, I thought about using something like ZoomIt, but it is Keyboard-Controlled. Is there some way to make it work with gestures or something that would work similar on a touch-only device (opening on-screen Keyboard kind of destroys any "smooth" working experience). Or a similar software that integrates nicely?